# Facebook Authentication - Blank white screen during authentication - iOS 10 GM, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication

Since Swift 3 - iOS 10, Xcode 8 GM SDK, I receive blank white screen at the end of the authentication with Facebook SDK.
It worked before. I have some warnings in the AppDelegate:

[image]

maybe it has something to do with it.

Edit:
I understood these functions are deprecated, and I tried changing these to the new functions, but the FBSDKApplicationDelegate still requests the older parameters...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: <#T##String!#>, annotation: <#T##Any!#>)
}
```

As you see, the problem is now with the second function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand these functions are deprecated in iOS 9, so that I used the others functions with their own API.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey
        .sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app,open: url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```